# How to remove reference from imported wikipedia table in R?

Tags: r, rvest

I want to import table from Wikipedia, but it contains reference links in brackets.

I import this table from 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics_of_the_COVID-19_pandemic_in_Poland

[image]

My code:

```
library("rvest")
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics_of_the_COVID-19_pandemic_in_Poland"
xpathd <- "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/table[2]"

dane <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = xpathd) %>%
  html_table()

dane <- dane[[1]]
head(dane)
```

When I use it I get data table with brackets with reference numbers:

[image]

How to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gsub()` to remove the pattern of reference parts.

```
library(dplyr)

dane %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = ~ gsub("\\[.*?\\]", "", .)))
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to use `parse_number` on the columns that you want to remove digits from.

```
library(dplyr)
new_data <- dane %>% 
               mutate(across(`Confirmed daily[c]`:`Unofficial deaths daily[f]`,
                      readr::parse_number))
```

`parse_number` returns the first number from the string.